# Why doesn't unary_function define operator()?

Tags: c++

I was just looking for a handy base class for a set of functors to be based on taking and int and returning void.

Thinking to use std/functional the functors are basically going to be `unary_function<int,void>` with `operator()`.

Why is `virtual result_type operator()(const argument_type& _Left) const = 0;` not defined on the unary_function template?  I'm guessing that it's because there could be variations in constness...
Is there some other template I've missed that includes the `operator()`?

I haven't done this in a while, am I missing something?

How would I also make use of existing functional like

```
std::ptr_fun< HWND, void >(someFunction);
std::pointer_to_unary_function<HWND, void>(someFunction);
```

**EDIT:** 
Perhaps I should include the other half of the usage to make this complete.  Maybe it's the usage half that is not fitting in with the concept.

How would one pass the functor to a method and use it?

```
typedef unary_function<int,void> Functor;

void DoStuff(const Functor& functor) {
  int demo = 1;
  functor(demo);
}
```

functor as a unary_function doesn't define operator() and so DoStuff doesn't compile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Template concepts are duck-typed. The fact that a class satisfying the `UnaryFunction` concept needs `operator()` is specified in the documentation and inferred from the templates which use template parameters satisfying that concept. There's no need to spell out the function signature, or to require that it be `virtual`, that it take a const reference parameter, or that it be a const member function.

The `unary_function` template should not be thought of as an interface (and it isn't designed as one). It's certainly not a polymorphic base class. It's a helper, which is used by classes that wish to implement the `AdaptableUnaryFunction` concept.

From the STL docs, which are reliable for the original design rationale: "the only reason it exists is to make defining Adaptable Unary Functions more convenient" - http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/unary_function.html

The standard is similar: "The following classes are provided to simplify the typedefs of the argument and result types" (20.3.1/1)

Advanced usage - actually what's required for UnaryFunction is that if `f` is a unary function object, and `x` is convertible to the argument type, then `f(x)` is a valid expression of the result type. It needn't have a one-argument `operator()` at all, it's fine to have a two-arg `operator()` with the second arg having a default value. Try defining that as a pure virtual function ;-)

Second question, you make use of `ptr_fun` just by calling it with function name/pointer. Its template parameters will be inferred from the function type, so you don't need to specify them. The result is an object of the corresponding `pointer_to_unary_function` template type.

To use the example straight from the STL docs:

```
transform(first, last, first,
    compose1(negate<double>, ptr_fun(fabs)));
```

This is approximately equivalent to:

```
for (auto current = first; current != last; ++current) {
    *current = -fabs(*current);
}
```

(where I use `auto` in its C++0x sense, meaning "I cannot be bothered / it is impossible to write the iterator type here")

A function name/pointer can be used in `transform` (which takes a `UnaryFunction` template parameter), but not in `compose1` (which takes an `AdapatableUnaryFunction` template parameter). So without `ptr_fun`, there's no way to compose `negate` with `fabs`.

In response to your Edit, I stress, **unary_function is not a polymorphic base class**. You cannot usefully use it (or any of its instantiations) as a function parameter type.

If you want to use the UnaryFunction or AdaptableUnaryFunction concepts, then you must write a function template:

```
template <typename UnaryFunction>
void DoStuff(UnaryFunction &functor) {
    int demo = 1;
    functor(demo);
}
```

This only requires that the functor take a type which `int` converts to, though. It doesn't require that it take exactly `int` and return exactly `void`. That's usually an advantage.

If a template doesn't do what you want, then `unary_function` is not for you. You haven't missed anything: you can design your own interface with a virtual `operator()`, but the standard libraries don't aim to provide any such thing.

Comment: Thanks for the detail, and the reminder of the stl::transform example which brought to mind the usage of templates to implement virtual.

Answer (score 2):

Because a virtual operator () is not a part of the unary_function concept.  The unary function concept can have a non-virtual operator in addition to differences in constness.